# Excel - Formula to get total number of worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 100+ sheets, it is hard for me to count them one by one.

Is there a one line formula to get the total number of sheets? The CELL or ADDRESS function perhaps?

I remember using something like this once, but I cannot seem to remember it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use a little bit of VB for that.

Try for "Table sheets -> without Diagrams"

```
Public Sub test()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
End Sub
```

Try for "All Sheets" -> including Diagrams

```
Public Sub test2()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty good post. As you are working to improve your answers, you may want to add steps how to implement what you suggest as the answer. In this case, keep in mind readers may not know how to add this code to the workbook. Also, please refrain from using signatures in your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a neat, formula-based solution.

1. Create a `New Name` in `Name Manager` called **wshNames**, with the value: 
   `=RIGHT(GET.WORKBOOK(1),LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1))-FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)))`
2. In any cell you want to show the number of worksheets, enter:   `=COUNTA(wshNames)`

[image]

**Note**: Step 1 relies on an XLM formula. [More on this here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/working-with-excel-4-0-macros-HA010336614.aspx) - note you will need to save as a .xlsm. This technique is borrowed from [David Hager](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/eee/P15/), via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371030/how-do-i-get-my-formula-to-always-reference-to-the-last-sheet).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the sheets formula, in any empty cell you can type
`=SHEETS()`
and that's it. it will count all the sheets in the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a module in the workbook of which you want to count the total number of sheets of.

Then copy in the below code and hit <kbd>run</kbd>

```
    Public Sub CountWorksheets()
       MsgBox "Total Sheets count:" & Application.Sheets.Count
    End Sub
```

You'll get a relevant output:

[image: click the link to see the screenshot]