# Does Excel provide any built-in, graphical way to view the list of all sheets, with the ability to click on a sheet, or do I have to do it myself?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Microsoft Excel [with](https://superuser.com/q/773113/116475) 370 sheets. Does Microsoft Excel provide any built-in, graphical way to view the list of all sheets, with the ability to click on a given sheet, or do I have to [do it myself](https://www.howtoexcel.org/tips-and-tricks/how-to-generate-a-list-of-sheet-names-from-a-workbook-without-vba/)?

E.g. Notepad++ provides a built-in, graphical way to view the list of all tabs:

[image]

Comment: 370 sheets! Why?! :.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right-click the arrows (pointing left/right) down in the lower left corner of the window ... to the left of your first sheet tab.

[image]

[image]

Example:

[image]